# Trying to make an authentication view for GET route but not POST in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, post, laravel, get, laravel-routing

### Edit:

I found that when the URLs are the same, the POST one isn't being used whatsoever. Filling the form redirects the user to the auth view even though its method is set to POST. It's as if either the form method was set to GET or I defined a `Route::any` to that URL. I did neither. Double checked.

I still see no reason for that to be happening.

---

### Main Question:

So, I have a view inside my app that needs to be accessible only to user who have a specific password (NOT their passwords as users) and a specific e-mail. To accomplish that, I put a form inside another view (accessible to everyone) and created a POST route as follows:

### teamv5.blade.php

```
         <form action="{{ URL::route('team-update-v5-post', array('v5',$team_v5->teamname)) }}" method='post'>
                <p>Team password: {{ $team_v5->teamname }}</p>
                <input type='password' name='password'>
                <input type='hidden' name='email' value="{{ Sentry::getUser()->email }}">
                <input type='submit' value='Edit'>
                {{ Form::token(); }}
        </form>
```

### Routes.php

```
 Route::post('/sentry/team/{v}/{teamname}/edit', array(
        'as'    => 'team-update-v5-post',
        'uses'  => 'TeamController@postUpdateV5'
 ));

 Route::get('/sentry/team/{v}/{teamname}/edit', array(
        'as'    => 'team-update-v5',
        'uses'  => 'TeamController@getUpdateV5'
  ));
```

So if the password is correct and the user's e-mail is the one authorized to access that view, it works and the information passes to the controller.

Now, problem is: I don't want anyone besides that specific user with that specific password to see the view, so I created a GET route for anyone that tries to simply type the URL in the browser. That route is supposed to make a authentication view that prompts the user to fill in the necessary info. Here is the controller:

### TeamController.php

```
    public function getUpdateV5 ($v,$teamname) {

            return View::make('team.auth')
                    ->with('v',$v)
                    ->with('teamname',$teamname);
    }

    public function postUpdateV5($v,$teamname) {

            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
                            'password'      => 'required|min:6',
                            'email'         => 'required|email',
            ));

            if($validator->fails()) {

                    return Redirect::route('team-update-v5',array('v5',$teamname))
                            ->withErrors($validator);
            } else {
                    $team_v5 = DB::table('teams_v5')->where('teamname',$teamname)->first();
                    $captain_v5 = Sentry::findUserById($team_v5->captain_id);

                    if(Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $team_v5->password)) {
                            return View::make('team.updatev5')
                                    ->with('team_v5', $team_v5)
                                    ->with('captain_v5',$captain_v5)
                     } else {

                            return Redirect::route('profile-team',array($v,$teamname))
                                    ->with('global','Incorrect password!');
                    }
            }
    }
```

At the end, what happens is:

1. If I write the same URL for the GET and POST routes, the GET one works but after filling that first form in `teamv5.blade.php`, the user gets redirected to the auth view and is prompted to type the info again (not nice).
2. If I write different URLs or simply comment out the GET route, the POST one works perfectly but when I try to reload the page or access it via URL, I get the HTTP METHOD NOT ALLOWED error (because, of course, no GET route is written for that URL).

I want the user to be able to access it both ways, if possible. I know I made it long, sorry. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i can't see what's the issue here. if password is incorrect, then you __must__ redirect the user to the form again so that, if he has made some mistake, he can correct it this time around. can you explain what problem you are having (with an example perhaps)?

Comment: @itachi I'll add to the question a few extra details I found out today.

Comment: @itachi The problem is not redirecting him to correct a mistake. It's that even when he fills everything correctly, he still gets the auth screen, as if the POST route was not working properly. And the auth form also redirects to itself, indicating it's using the GET method.  It looks like a route problem but there is no reason for that.

Comment: are you sure your authentication is successful? as far as i can guess, the hashing mechanism of laravel and sentry may not be same and hence, the authentication is always failing even after entering the correct password.

Comment: @itachi I'll check on that but that's not probably it since I've already tried manipulating  the post function. Instead of redirecting the user to the same page I returned 'fail' only for testing purposes and even that did not work (before attempting to authenticate, of course). The method always seems to be GET for some reason. I'm at a loss.